# java double free or corruption

Tags: java, ubuntu

maybe stupid question but i'm getting randomly following error when running my *.jar package. Sometimes programm runs flawlessly and sometimes interrupts putting this out in console:

```
*** Error in 'java': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f665c04a830 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7f66c63d7a46]
/usr/lib/libjnetpcap.so(Java_org_jnetpcap_nio_JMemoryReference_disposeNative0+0xa6)[0x7f66b55f20eb]
[0x7f66bc5cd738]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2752983                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:02 2752983                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 2752983                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
006d2000-006f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
77b000000-77c500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
77c500000-785600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
785600000-78a780000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
78a780000-7d7200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7d7200000-7d9b00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7d9b00000-800000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f664c000000-7f664c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f664c021000-7f6650000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6654000000-7f6654021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6654021000-7f6658000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6658000000-7f6658021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6658021000-7f665c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f665c000000-7f665c0ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f665c0ac000-7f6660000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6660000000-7f6660021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6660021000-7f6664000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6664000000-7f66641ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66641ad000-7f6668000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6668000000-7f6668021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6668021000-7f666c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f666c000000-7f666c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f666c021000-7f6670000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6670000000-7f6670021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6670021000-7f6674000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6674000000-7f6674021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6674021000-7f6678000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f667969a000-7f667969d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f667969d000-7f667979b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5820]
7f667979b000-7f667979e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f667979e000-7f667989c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5819]
7f667989c000-7f667989f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f667989f000-7f667999d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5818]
7f667999d000-7f6679bbd000 rw-s 00000000 00:07 220407                     socket:[220407]
7f6679bbd000-7f6679bc0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6679bc0000-7f6679cbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5817]
7f6679cbe000-7f6679cc1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6679cc1000-7f6679dbf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5816]
7f6679dbf000-7f6679fdf000 rw-s 00000000 00:07 219343                     socket:[219343]
7f6679fdf000-7f6679fe2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6679fe2000-7f667a0e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:5814]
7f667a0e0000-7f667a0fb000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970077                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052003l.pfb
7f667a0fb000-7f667a10d000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970041                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019043l.pfb
7f667a10d000-7f667a126000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970000                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/b018012l.pfb
7f667a12f000-7f667a130000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f667a130000-7f667a133000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 17236023                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f667a133000-7f667a143000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1969994                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010033l.pfb
7f667a143000-7f667a14f000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970025                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/d050000l.pfb
7f667a14f000-7f667a164000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970006                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/b018032l.pfb
7f667a164000-7f667a177000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970003                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/b018015l.pfb
7f667a177000-7f667a191000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970012                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059013l.pfb
7f667a191000-7f667a1a8000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970094                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/z003034l.pfb
7f667a1a8000-7f667a1c3000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970080                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052004l.pfb
7f667a1c3000-7f667a1d4000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970047                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019063l.pfb
7f667a1d4000-7f667a1e5000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1969997                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010035l.pfb
7f667a1e5000-7f667a1ee000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970089                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/s050000l.pfb
7f667a1ee000-7f667a1fe000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1969991                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010015l.pfb
7f667a1fe000-7f667a21a000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970086                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052024l.pfb
7f667a21a000-7f667a232000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970022                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059036l.pfb
7f667a232000-7f667a24d000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970083                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052023l.pfb
7f667a24d000-7f667a25f000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970009                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/b018035l.pfb
7f667a25f000-7f667a26f000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1969988                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010013l.pfb
7f667a26f000-7f667a28a000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970015                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059016l.pfb
7f667a28a000-7f667a29c000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970044                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019044l.pfb
7f667a29c000-7f667a2af000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970050                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019064l.pfb
7f667a2af000-7f667a2c7000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1970018                    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059033l.pfb
7f667a2c7000-7f667a2e5000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1275703                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb
7f667a2e5000-7f667a307000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1978245                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qplr.pfb
7f667a307000-7f667a327000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1978229                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qbkbi.pfb
7f667a327000-7f667a341000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1978241                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qagbi.pfb
7f667a341000-7f667a35c000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1275730                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmtcsc10.pfb
7f667a35c000-7f667a376000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1978256                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qhvbi.pfb
7f667a376000-7f667a37f000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1969318                    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/c0649bt_.pfb
7f667a37f000-7f667a3a1000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1275718                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmtlco10.pfb
7f667a3a1000-7f667a3c1000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1978224                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qtmbi.pfb
7f667a3c1000-7f667a3de000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1275759                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmssqbx8.pfb
7f667a3de000-7f667a3f9000 r--s 00000000 08:02 1275756                    /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsso10.pfb
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, running:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The error does not come from Java but from a native library. If you are not using JNI probably it is not your fault but a problem with the installation.

Comment: To be honest you might want to hit up the jnetpcap forums for this one. I also recommend trying to create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. If you followed all proper installation instructions, it seems like either an issue in their library, or an issue in their documentation (leading you to use something incorrectly / install improperly).

Comment: Code is too complex to post it as it consist of several classes, however is there any guess what can be the reason of this error? Maybe I could find some method to avoid it :/

Comment: @user3435174 It is absolutely 100% impossible for us to give you even a remote guess, unfortunately. Minimal test case = win.

Comment: [They also have a mailing list](http://jnetpcap.com/support) (and seem to have been responsive about [addressing such issues](http://jnetpcap.com/node/836) in the past).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know that this is an old thread but just in case someone fails in the same error.

> This is a multi-threading issue with a native library you are using.

To cut the long story short, the java loads the native library into memory then it is accessed by multiple threads at the same time, then this error pops up.

A quick workaround for this issue is to mark the method that generating this error as `synchronized`.

---

### Update after @kit comment.

It is not possible to run such native library in multi-threading environment.

Your options are:

- modify the native library to make it thread-safe (if you have access to its code).
- wrap it as an application and run multiple copies as separate processes (because native library is loaded once per process)
- wrap it as a service and run multiple copies, talking to it using Sockets or an appropriate higher-level RPC mechanism.

Credits: [Load the same dynamic library in two threads (both threads in the same JVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042610/java-load-the-same-dynamic-library-in-two-threads-both-threads-in-the-same-jvm)

Comment: Thanks for that. Fixed my issue straight away !

Comment: @AhmedHassanien- Is their any other solution for this because I want to execute such a code concurrently with multiple threads without synchronization?

Comment: what is the relevant string in the output in the op which reveals this to be the  threading issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and solved it. I attached 2 different java agents: Skywalking-java-agent \ JVMSandbox-java-agent to the same JVM process, when the JVM started， the error occurs.
I solved this question by modifying the Skywalking-java-agent's config file agent.config located in skywalking-agent/config:

```html
agent.is_cache_enhanced_class=${SW_AGENT_CACHE_CLASS:false}
```

change this default value to true and restart the JVM process, then resolve it.

I hope this could be helpful.