# SBT test fails with "`java': double free or corruption" error

Tags: java, scala, jvm, sbt

I'm running `sbt test` in a multi-project build, and the tests keep failing randomly with a "double free or corruption" error.

Example (truncated) output:

```
[info] 
[info] Passed: Total 9, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 9
*** Error in `java': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007faac8027d70 ***
/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 41:  8420 Aborted                 (core dumped) 

"$@"
```

The command fails every time I run the tests, but always at a different point.

I've found another StackOverflow question that suggests that this could be about multi-threaded access to a native library, but I'm at a loss on how to begin to figure out which part of the code might be causing this. (It's a fairly large project with about twenty external dependencies (not counting transitive ones).)

Could you point me towards how to best debug this?

**Extra steps I've tried:**

- running `sbt clean test` and then `sbt test-quick` means the second command passes, even if the first one failed with the strange error. (It still fails if there's a bug caught by the unit tests.)
- running `sbt clean test` for each project individually doesn't reproduce this error

Comment: Firstly figure out how to reproduce it regularly.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491797/java-double-free-or-corruption

Comment: @LouisF. Thanks, I've already seen that question before posting this. I'm just at a loss at how to pinpoint which part of the build might be causing this error. (As I added to my question, running the same command project by project doesn't reproduce the error even after several tries.)