# sbt - double free or corruption (!prev) error whenever running mocha tests

Tags: scala, sbt, mocha.js

I've got an sbt project that I run front-end tests on with `sbt mocha`.  Whenever I attempt to do so, I get the below error.  Everything else runs properly - I can do `sbt test` which will run my specs2 scala tests but error out on the mocha tests.  I can even run the project itself without issue.

```
com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$JsTaskFailure: double free or corruption (!prev)

at com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$jse$SbtJsTask$$executeJsOnEngine$1.apply(SbtJsTask.scala:218)
at com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$jse$SbtJsTask$$executeJsOnEngine$1.apply(SbtJsTask.scala:190)
at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[error] (<projectnameredacted>/*:mochaExecuteTests) com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask$JsTaskFailure: double free or corruption (!prev)`
```

I've tried doing an `sbt clean`, I've tried deleting the `.ivy2` and `.sbt` directories, forcing sbt to rebuild itself.

I'm running sbt 0.13.17 and, due to this being a company project, cannot change the sbt version.  It's also utilizing scala 2.12.7.

From what I've read, the issue comes from trying to load multiple instances of standard libraries, but the error I'm getting doesn't come from any of the standard libraries, it comes from an sbt package that the project requires and has used without issue for months.  [Here is where I got that information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491797/java-double-free-or-corruption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with my version of Node.js.  Once I updated from 10.0.0 to 11.2.0 the issue went away.