# Parallel invokation of non reentrant native function using JNA

Tags: java, dll, jvm, jna

I'd like to parallelize calls to a native library (DLL) that is not reentrant. Two threads should call the native function in parallel. I want to use JNA to access the DLL. Locks are not a solution since this is not parallelism.

My thoughts until now:

- Thread pool with threads holding each a Proxy instance to the DLL loaded with Native.loadLibrary() (it might only work if the DLL can be loaded multiple times in one JVM and do not share any state)
- Thread pool with threads holding each a Proxy instance to its own physical DLL with a different name. Each loaded with Native.loadLibrary(). (it might only work if for the same Library interface, multiple DLL can be loaded)
- Do I need to load the DLL in different JVMs for parallelism.

Does anyone know whether one of these thoughts might work / or why it can't work. Other suggestions?
Thanks, Martin

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042610/java-load-the-same-dynamic-library-in-two-threads-both-threads-in-the-same-jvm

Comment: You would need as many copies of the DLL as you want parallelism, each loaded under a unique name.  This assumes that the library itself does not choke under such usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you can't load the same DLL twice into one process. I say your best option for achieving parallelism is to have several processes executing concurrently, instead of one process.

Comment: You can't on Linux either, and I would not expect that any OS would allow it. A DLL/SO works via a jump table that is bound to method invocations. These bindings are not thread-local.

Comment: How is it with physically different DLLs. Basically copy the DLL and rename it. Would that create new jump table to different addresses? If yes, can I access the two libraries using the same JNA Library interface or is there a limitation by JNA?

Comment: What if you have 8 cores? Will you rename the DLL 16 times?

Comment: I admit, it is not an elegant solution, but yes probably I would do it as temporary solution...if it works.

Comment: I wouldn't dare call it a solution. The library might crash hard if used this way. Running multiple processes is more straightforward, more scalable and also a very common technique. Just use that.